# How to get Jenkins to perform deletes on remote server

Tags: git, deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to get started with an automated build process using Jenkins.

So far i have managed to get Jenkins to build a project from BitBucket, run tests and upload the files to a production server using the Publish Over SSH plugin.

When i delete files from my git repo, i would like those files to be deleted on the remote server. There are a few ways that i have thought about doing this already.

1. Wipe all the files on the production server, then upload the latest build release.

   - seems like a bad solution for me, as this would cause more downtime than i would like.
2. Create a script that lives on the remote server to clean up the files after the new build process. I would need to find out from git (somehow?) what the deleted files on that commit were.
3. Instead of having Jenkin use the publish over ssh plugin, have git installed on the production server, so after a successful build, we can get Jenkins (somehow?) to push the project to the git production server.

This seems like a common task for developers, and i feel like i am missing something here. Is there any standard practice for this.

Comment: You have to differentiate if this is a Dev sandbox server, or a Production live machine. For Production, always deploy from a clearly defined package, i.e delete old, upload new. You can configure all sorts of `diffs` and `rsync` to upload *just* the differences. For Dev sandboxes, there is nothing wrong in having `git` directly in the server, and update it as the files get changed in `git`

Comment: For production, you recommend that i should delete the entire package? Currently Jenkins takes nearly an hour to upload, is this normal?

Comment: Normal? Depends on your package size, network bandwidth and protocol used. What *is* the "normal" time to upload your files to server if done "manually"?

Comment: Package size is roughly 200 mb and growing, 1gb bandwidth p/m, and using sftp. If was to transfer manually through ftp would take roughly 10 minutes

Comment: What would a large enterprise do, as they would not want any downtime on their application?

Comment: Write a deployment script, don't rely on "Publish Over SSH" (actually you could still use that plugin to copy over package [to temp directory] and deploy script, and then trigger it). This way, the "upload time" does not factor into your downtime. You could even extract the package into a temp directory before incurring downtime, and finally do a quick "rename" or even "symlink switch". Depending on software/code you may or may not need to restart the web server. Subject of "zero-downtime release" is a very lengthy and tricky subject

Comment: And if it takes you 10 minutes manually, and 1 hour through Jenkins, you really need to review the logs and find where the bottleneck is. It shouldn't be like that

Comment: Yes that sounds like a great solution, i will have to try something like that, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Cleaning the remote directory before deployment**

I was able to do it in the following way:

1. In the **Job** configuration in the **Build Environment** section, check **Send files or execute commands over SSH before the build starts**.
2. Delete the files of the previous version of the build on the remote server:

```
sudo rm -r /var/www/html/*
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is too late this answer, but I think other people search for this. I found a solution to delete file on the production server after you delete them in development.
In Jenkins, you use rsync to synchronize files between dev and production. add to this line at the end
    --delete
and this will do the trick

Comment: The author uses "Publish Over SSH plugin", which in turn uses `scp` under the hood, which does not have any `--delete` flags (and plugin does not provide any options to solve this issue too)